# How to fix "Content is not allowed in prolog" build error?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

When I upgraded to Android Studio 0.6.1, I encountered a build issue with asset files. I kept getting "Content is not allowed in prolog" during the mergeDebugResources task. Since I couldn't find a suitable answer to this and have since found a solution, I've answered my own question to help other developers who face this issue.

Answer (score 18):

It seems that the recent build changes since AS 0.6.1 and AS 0.8.1 no longer ignore custom asset directories. As a result, to get around the dreaded "Content is not allowed in prolog" you'll need to move your font files, properties and xml files to "src/main/assets" instead of your custom mapped assets directory. I hope this helps.

Comment: I lost almost a day with FileNotFound exception, for files inside **assets/someSubfolder**. When I moved the file inside **assets** I got your error. Your solution helped me realize that I was wrong putting **assets** folder inside src/main/res/assets, instead of just **src/main/assets**

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue in this way, first create directory "src/main/assets/fonts" and paste the file then mention this code in build.gradle

```
android { sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets/fonts/', 'src/main/assets/fonts/'] } } }
```